# Easy way to test AJAX Post?

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have an app setup that continually sends a value via AJAX POST.

I need to know whether the POST is happening and sending the correct values.

Are there ways to do this that don't involve setting up a database to store received values?

Comment: create a log function and do a `var_dump($_POST, true);`

Comment: @Class note that `var_dump($var, TRUE)` will not work as you might expect. If you need the contents of a variable in a string use `print_r($var, true);` If you really need the outputs of `var_dump()` and not `print_r()` in a string then you'll have to use output buffering

Answer (score 1):

On PHP side do just a

```
 var_dump($_POST);
```

or if you need that in a file

```
// Make sure that 'debug.txt' is writable
file_put_contents('debug.txt', print_r($_POST), true));
```

---

Update: Seems that I've not read the question carefully. I first thought that you are looking for some client side tools for testing. So I wrote the following answer.. However it may be interesting too for you and therefore I didn't deleted it...

If you are working with firefox I like the [poster plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/poster/). It's a nice tool to test all sorts of HTTP requests

If you prefer the command line (like me) I would suggest to use wget or curl

Using curl:

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://yourserver/your.php
```

Using wget:

```
wget -O - --post-data="param1=value1&param2=value2" http://yourserver/your.php
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work :)